# Can words with the same word root/stem be considered synonymous?

Tags: text, nlp, nltk, information-retrieval, porter-stemmer

Basically, can two words with the same root/stem word be considered synonymous, in particular when being used in a search engine/information retrieval context?

Answer (score 1):

No. *Work* (noun) and *work* (verb) are not synonymous.

Neither are *work* and *workout*

Comment: Even though English is a weakly inflected language? Can't stemmed words be considered synonymous for indexing/search purposes?  Like:
        CONNECT
        CONNECTED
        CONNECTING
        CONNECTION
        CONNECTIONS
?

Comment: There are obviously many cases where no such distinction is meaningful, but you are asking is this always true, and it obviously isn't. The other answer argues that *statistically* you could ignore this phenomenon, but I'd certainly not forget that it's there or pretend it doesn't exist.

Comment: I agree with both. I'll combine both into my answer. Yes you can argue that stemmed words are synonymous for the purpose of information retrieval, however there are many exceptions, such as the one you mentioned above,  that cannot be glossed over. 
Does this seem like a fair statement?

Answer (score 0):

> can two words with the same root/stem word be considered synonymous,

etymoligical root is different from stem. word with the same stem are not necessarly synonymous.

> in particular when being used in a search engine/information retrieval context?

Yes. Actually it's the prefered approach to record stems in the inverted index and then filter then score the results based on the actual query.

If you are interested in handling synonyms I recommend this [post on algolia blog](https://blog.algolia.com/inside-the-engine-part-6-handling-synonyms-the-right-way/) and the [related documentation](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/textual-relevance/synonyms/).

Answer (score -1):

While there may be exceptions, and there are many, if you want to look at it statistically then the answer is Yes. Especially if you are looking at search engine application, I think this is a good assumption to go with. You can later device some layer over it to handle exceptions.

Comment: Please provide a link or explanation to your, as you say, "statistical" justification of your answer. A stem itself does not contain any information about its sematic/context/grammar/..., so accepting any other similar written word to be synonym cannot be "handled later" as "exception" as you say. You are not even able to estimate the error-impact on your nlp-task deriving from your described shotgun-like approach - Again, please describe your statistical justification why you argue that this has only a neglectable effect.